# How does an Objective-C property setter signal failure?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, memory-management, setter

Suppose you have a property with copy semantics. What should you do in the setter if the copy method fails? (I presume this is a possibility, since a copy usually starts with an alloc/init combo, which can fail and return nil.) Apple recommends returning error codes rather than using exceptions, but a setter generally has a void return type. What is the recommended approach? How do you signal that an error has occurred?

Comment: Why do you think alloc / init will fail ? I have never seen this happen.

Comment: "I've never seen a black swan. Therefore, they don't exist."

Comment: I don't know if alloc can fail (I'm still trying to find any details on that), but any initializer can fail and return nil, for any number of reasons. I tend to code defensively and I've not found anything that says that copy cannot fail, so I assume that it can. That said, I would think that it would be pretty rare that copy could fail for any reason but memory exhaustion (since all the object values should be valid). So if alloc cannot fail (except by taking down your whole program), then perhaps it's pretty unlikely that copy would ever fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to signal an error, other than that the property whose setter you called would be `nil`. You can check for `nil` after executing the setter, just as you would to confirm success after alloc/init'ing a new instance.

Comment: OK, so you would release the old value of the property even if the new value could not be copied?

Comment: Yeah, I'd definitely release the old value.

Comment: Thanks, Ole. Both answers are basically getting at the same thing, but I found this one a little clearer (after the clarification about releasing the old value), which is why I'm accepting this over CRD's. But both are useful and appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @big_m Keep in mind that calling any method on `nil` will just return `nil` (tho properties are a bit stickier).  So if you get `nil` back and try to `retain` it, it'll silently succeed until you try to doing something more complicated with the `nil` (e.g. getting a value type out of it).  This is an intentional feature of the language— rather than having to check for `nil` frequently throughout your code, you can (theoretically) just do a bunch of stuff and then do one `nil` check.  The modern-day reality is less optimistic but it's still worth considering, especially for `retain`/`release`.

Answer (score 6):

The Apple recommendation is really that exceptions should be reserved for exceptional situations. This is sometimes a recommended programming practice anyway, but in the case of Objective-C is reinforced due to the higher cost of exception handling.

So you can throw an exception if you wish and it is appropriate, e.g. running out of memory (copy failed) is (hopefully!) exceptional.

That said, some programming practices also recommend that properties should not throw exceptions; usually on the basis that something that looks like assignment `obj.property = value;` would be confusing if exceptions were thrown (unlike `[obj setProperty:value]`).

So that get us to setting the property to the "zero" for the type (`nil`, `0`, `0.0`, `NO` etc.).

To return more details of the error record details of the error which can be queried after the "zero" has been detected. This is essentially the approach used by the underlying ("Unix") syscalls, and many library functions, were `errno` is set before a "zero" is returned.

Comment: My impression of Apple's exception guidelines is that they want you to use them only for programmer errors, not runtime errors (e.g. memory issues). Setting to nil seems like a reasonable alternative, though see my comment to @Ole.

Comment: The guideline is to use them for exceptions - e.g. `NSString rangeOfString:` will throw an exception if its argument is `nil`.